# Compiling Arduino functions under IAR

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, iar

I'm sorry to ask that kind of simple questions but I'm struggling to get over it.
I'm trying to compile a subset of Arduino library (print.cpp) under IAR but I can't get it to work.
Under GCC and MSVC it's working but when trying to do it using IAR ARM I'm getting error `"Error[Pe338]: more than one instance of overloaded function "operator+" has "C" linkage"` in following code in WString.h

```
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, const String &rhs);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, const char *cstr);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, char c);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, unsigned char num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, int num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, unsigned int num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, long num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, unsigned long num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, float num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, double num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, const __FlashStringHelper *rhs);
```

When using automatic C/C++ mode IAR defaults to "C", so I forced it in C++ mode.

Comment: You should remove the C language tag, since the keyword `friend` is not a keyword in C.  Also, you can't overload functions or operators in the C language.

Comment: OK, tag removed. I'm compiling the code in C++ mode but compiler says something about "C linkage"...

Comment: A `friend` declaration is not a function declaration.  Post a _complete_ build log; it is likely to contain useful diagnostic information.  C linkage occurs when a symbol is declared `extern "C"` in C++.  Since C linkage does not support function or operator overloading, such functions cannot be declared `extern "C"`.  The question therefore is why the compiler has determined that it has?

Comment: If the error is reported for these `friend` declarations, then _freindship_ is also incompatible with C linkage and you need to be sure  that these declarations do not occur in a an `extern "C"{...}` block.  Other compilers might simply ignore the error or ignore the `extern "C"`  for friends, as it makes little sense.